# Run RSpec specs marked with custom metadata first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I would like to run some specs that are marked with `:first` in the beginning of an RSpec session. So, if I have:

```
describe 'one' { ... }
describe 'two', :first { ... }
describe 'three' { ... }
```

the order in which I want specs to be run is `two`, `one`, `three`.

Can this be done with RSpec?

Note: I know it's counterproductive to run tests in a certain order, but I need a quick workaround for our project so that all specs pass (unfortunately some specs are poorly written and fail depending on the order in which they are run).

Comment: can't you just move those which should run first to the top?

Comment: How to move them and on top of what?

Comment: cut and paste? `describe 'two' { ... } \n describe 'one' { ... } \n describe 'three' { ... }`. on top of the spec file

Comment: They are defined in many files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RSpec` has an [`--order` flag](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/order) you can pass to define a specific order. By default, this flag understands only a couple of strategies, such as `random` or `seed`, where the seed is a specific instance of a random order.

However, if you dig into the [`Ordering` module](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/v3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/ordering.rb), you will see you can define new ordering strategies.

There is a [`Custom` strategy](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/v3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/ordering.rb#L60-L68) which apparently orders by a specific block. These strategies are managed by an ordering register, and dependent on the [`:order` config](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/v3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb#L1163-L1187).

You can investigate the internals, define a custom order strategy based on your rules, and make it the default.

Comment: Thank you! The docs should be more clear on every aspect you can do with RSpec.

Comment: This is a very specific need, not even covered by the standard cases. Please note that the order registry is defined as private API, hence RSpec doesn't officially allow what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Looks like there is a case described in the docs: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/configuration/overriding-global-ordering. I don't find my case to be that specific; anyway, the docs should be more detailed in general.

Comment: And here is the official issue for custom ordering, for reference: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/547

Comment: @AndreiHorak that's interesting, yes, apparently there is a limited customization possible from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

To run your tests in a specific order you need to arrange the tests in the order you would like them to be run then run the `rspec` command with the `--order default` flag:

```
rspec --order default
```

If you run `rspec` without this flag the tests will be run in a random order (as I'm sure you've noticed).

**Source**:

The release notes from 2012 when Rspec added this flag - http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/blog/2012/01/04/rspec-28-is-released/